# What does the fdim acronym stand for?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, acronym

All C math functions seems to have an understandable name, but I can't find what the fdim acronym stands for.
(fdim computes the positive difference of it two floating-point inputs).

Comment: Float difference, ignoring minus? Does it really matter? :-)

Comment: It's been bugging me for a while, and I can't find the answer in the all the documentation I've red so far, so it matters to me =)

Comment: Finding the rationale to the standard lib in general and its naming is much like attempting to make sense of a drunk person talking in their sleep. I can make the attempt by peeking in old K&R etc for you, but I doubt I'll find much.

Comment: @Lundin, already looked, `fdim` doesn't exist in KnR1 or 2 or c89, it seems to first show up in C99. I *do* like the idea that C lib came from a bunch of drunken louts, that explains quite a bit :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Aye, I just realized that too. Checking C99 rationale.

Comment: @Lundin I've been looking in the K&R as well as the C99 standard. Also looked inside of the Khronos OpenCL documentation, as well as various other standards but no one mention the naming.

Comment: I suspect it's just an arbitrary name that doesn't really map to the functionality (returning the positive difference between two values), but fits with the general naming convention for similar functions.  `fdif` would make more sense, except adding the `f` suffix for `float`s would give you `fdiff`, which most people would likely type out of habit and result in an extra edit/compile cycle (with some associated bitching).  Or you could call it `fdiff` and the float version would be `fdifff`, which ... no.

Comment: @JohnBode Indeed, `fdim()` - contrary to many manpages and descriptions floating around - doesn't really calculate the "positive difference" (which would be `|x-y|`) in a mathematical sense, but is really a _subtraction with saturation_.

Comment: @Ctx - you're right, looking at N1570 again, `fdim(x,y)` returns `x - y` if `x > y` and `+0` if `x <= y`.  IOW, `x - y` constrained to a non-negative result.  Which ... okay.  I don't do any number crunching.  I assume there's a use case for it, I just don't know what that would be.

Comment: I searched the ISO-C working group [document archive](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/documents) and best I can tell `fdim()` must have been added to the proposed new C9x standard prior to 1996, very likely in one of the floating-point related proposals by Jim Thomas (who proposed `isinf()` and `fma()` in N619, for example). Unfortunately, electronic copies of those early documents are not linked from the archive.

Comment: I tried to contact Jim Thomas using his most recent email address at HP that I could find, but alas, the email bounced.

Comment: `DIM` was part of the Fortran 77 standard. At a guess, C stole the name from there, so you'll likely need the Fortran historians to find out where the name came from.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I believe to have found an explanation for the name in the F77 manual

Comment: @albert: I notice you removed the "fortran" tag, but it _is_ relevant here. The "fdim" name (or at least the "dim" part of it) wasn't original to C; it occurred in FORTRAN 77, so it makes sense to add the tag to attract Fortran experts who might know more about where the name originated from.

Comment: @MarkDickinson where did you see the `dim`? The only `dim` I know of is the `dim=` to indicate the dimension of an operation like in `findloc`. I checked the FORTRAN 77 and Fortran 2019 standards and in neither of the two I could find the word `fdim`.

Comment: @albert Fortran 77 has `DIM`. (Not `fdim`: the `f` here is just a common prefix for floating-point functions.) See for example https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DIM.html, or the link given in the answer from @Ctx. You can also find it in the standard itself if you look hard enough (it's in table 5, "Intrinsic Functions")

Comment: Actually, it looks as though it's even in the [Fortran 66 standard](https://wg5-fortran.org/ARCHIVE/Fortran66.pdf) (page 23, Table 3, intrinsic functions).

Comment: @MarkDickinson I do see the `dim` function (with description: DIM (X, Y) E Maximum of X − Y and zero.) and I also saw some functions that just differ in the output type like idim, ddim, qdim, but no fdim. One is never to old to learn.

Answer (score 5):

I searched the ISO-C working group's [document archive](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/documents), and noticed that most of the proposals for the floating-point enhancements to what would become C99 were contributed by Jim Thomas. Best I can tell, `fdim` was included in the draft new standard prior to 1996, and unfortunately the archive does not provide links to electronic copies for proposals from that time.

So I contacted Mr. Thomas directly via email and received a response, the relevant portion of which I quote here with his permission:

> From: Jim Thomas
>   To: Norbert Juffa
>   Time: Sat 2/15/2020 8:42 AM
>   Subject: Re: Naming of, and rationale for, the fdim() function in ISO-C99
>   [...]
>   The C fdim function is the C versions for the Fortran DIM (positive difference) function. The C function, and its name, were intended for programmers porting code form Fortran to C.

This confirms the linkage with Fortran alluded to in comments. As for the name `DIM` itself, [Ctx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60228460/780717) addresses this as well as one could hope for in the case of a minor function that has been around for fifty years.

In comments below the question, [Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) pointed to the [Fortran 66 standard](https://wg5-fortran.org/ARCHIVE/Fortran66.pdf), which on page 23 defined Fortran's `DIM` function as *a₁ - Min (a₁, a₂)*. This provides further evidence that the name `DIM` is a contraction of **DI**fference and **M**inimum.

Comment: @Ctx I find it not only interesting, I find it important that we preserve these little bits of computing history, and who better to ask than the people who made that history?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is, that it is a composition from `difference` and `max`, because this is what the function does.

Pseudo-code

```
double fdim(x, y) { 
    float    tmp = x - y;        // 1st step: "di"fference
    float result = fmax(tmp, 0); // 2nd step: "m"aximum
    return result;
}
```

Same nomenclature for example with `fma(a, b, c)`, which means "multiply" and "add" `(a*b+c)`

**Edit:**

The function indeed occurred even earlier in **Fortran**, where the function
`DIM(number, number)` is defined as

> A function that returns the value of the first argument minus the minimum (MIN) of the two arguments.

so the function name is derived from *difference* and *minimum* here. See the [F77 DIM manual](http://hecnet.eu/conan?key=F77~Intrinsic_Procedures~DIM)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any good published first source for this. `fdim` first appeared in C99, and the C99 rationale (7.12.12) only mentions this:

> The names for fmax, fmin and fdim have f prefixes to allow for
>   extension integer versions following the example of fabs and abs.

But we could already guess as much, the `f` stands for floating point.

Similarly, the last `f` in `fdimf` stands for `float`, and the last `l` in `fdiml` stands for `long double`. These prefix/postfix letters are commonly used in the standard libs.

Comment: Wildly speculating, `di` could mean difference, but that doesn't explain the `m`. Or `dim` could possibly mean dimension, but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I hoped for a moment to find an answer by looking at the interger definition of `dim`, but it did not help..

Comment: @Pyoz_ There might not be any explanation. Some of these functions were named by a cat walking across the keyboard. Take `strpbrk` for example.

Comment: @Lundin cppreference believes to have the explanation for this name: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk The roots are believed to be in snobol (http://www.snobol4.org/docs/burks/tutorial/ch4.htm point 4.8.4)